# Exporting bash function in .profile or .xprofile kills X during login

Tags: gnome, bash, login, xorg

I'm trying to export a bash function during Gnome login using one of the login shell start-up scripts. I've tried doing it in ~/.profile and ~/.xprofile but it results in X dying and restarting at the login screen.

I am able to export environment variables from these scripts without problems during Gnome login; only exporting a function (any function, regardless of content) kills X.

I can also source both scripts from a terminal and the function is exported as expected without any problems. The function also gets exported fine if the scripts are invoked by a bash login shell (`bash -l`) from a terminal.

Why is exporting a function at Gnome login killing X? / Can I do anything to fix it?

(I realise I could export the function from .bashrc, but using a profile is more convenient in my situation and I'd like to understand why this crash is happening.)

Comment: It would seem useful to provide the function in question.

Comment: @Ward, it happens with any function. I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX sh does not allow functions to be exported, but bash does. `~/.profile` is sourced by a POSIX shell, not bash. It's also rather pointless to export functions since only bash can read and use them. Just put the functions in `~/.bashrc`, and don't export them.

Comment: That makes sense. I had been working on CentOS and Darwin for a few days and both seem to run GUI logins through bash shells (allowing function exports from `/etc/profile` and `.bash_profile` that become available to all subsequent bash shells). Lesson learnt :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect. POSIX-compliant shells do allow functions to be exported.

The problem you had is probably because you were using the `function` keyword. POSIX syntax does not use `function`. Remove the `function` keyword and make sure you have parentheses after the function name and login will work again.